# CSV data with a variable number of table columns using csvsimple-l3

Tags: csv, csvsimple-l3

I have two CSV files. One has 5 columns and the other has 6 columns.

It is necessary to check the CSV file and determine the number of columns, which I managed to do. I saved the number of columns in \mycolumncount.

Furthermore, I made a condition to generate the corresponding table based on the number of columns, but for this part I can't get the output table.

It is important to note that it is necessary to use the csvsimple-l3 package.

What's wrong?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
 a,b,c,d,e
 1,2,3,4,5
 4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetColumnCount}{m}
{
\int_zero_new:N \l_tmpa_int
\ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#1}
\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
    \int_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_int {\l_tmpa_int}
  }
\int_use:N \g_tmpa_int
\ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\customtable}[1]{%
\edef\mycolumncount{\GetColumnCount{#1}}
%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycolumncount}{5}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
    \hline
    \csvreader[
      head to column names,
      late after line=\\\hline,
    ]{#1}{}{%
     \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv
   }
  \end{tabular}
 }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycolumncount}{6}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
    \hline
    \csvreader[
     head to column names,
     late after line=\\\hline,
   ]{#1}{}{%
     \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi
   }
  \end{tabular}
  }{}
 }
 }

 \begin{document}

 \customtable{file1.csv}

 The number of columns is: \mycolumncount.

 \end{document}
```

I don't have a table on the output, but only information about the number of columns.
I also note the important information that the columns of the table are of different widths.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `\GetColumnCount` is not expandable, as written.  Since I am not L3 savvy, I resort to the `readarray` package to obtain the column count, which is provided in `\ncols` after a `\readdef` is performed.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
 a,b,c,d,e
 1,2,3,4,5
 4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\customtable}[1]{%
\readdef{#1}\filedata
\let\mycolumncount\ncols
%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycolumncount}{5}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
    \hline
    \csvreader[
      head to column names,
      late after line=\\\hline,
    ]{#1}{}{%
     \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv
   }
  \end{tabular}
 }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\mycolumncount}{6}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
    \hline
    \csvreader[
     head to column names,
     late after line=\\\hline,
   ]{#1}{}{%
     \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi
   }
  \end{tabular}
  }{}
 }
 }

\begin{document}
\customtable{file1.csv}

The number of columns is: \mycolumncount.

\customtable{file2.csv}

The number of columns is: \mycolumncount.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The identical result can be obtained purely with the facilities of `readarray` as follows, which does not require the column count to be checked as part of the `\customtable` macro:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
 a,b,c,d,e
 1,2,3,4,5
 4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\\hline}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}

\newcommand{\customtable}[1]{%
  \readdef{#1}\myfile
  \readarray*\myfile\myfiledata[-,\ncols]%
  \initarray\myabbrevdata[\numexpr\nrows-1\relax,\ncols]%
  \mergearray\myfiledata\myabbrevdata[0,1]%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\ncols}{c|}}
  \hline
  \typesetarray\myabbrevdata\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\customtable{file1.csv}

The number of columns is: \ncols.

\customtable{file2.csv}

The number of columns is: \ncols.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the help. I managed to make the solution I needed.

Comment: @ZeljkoHrcek I found an error in my original post.  I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.